# Check first character in String in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, nasm

Im using NASM

I'd like to compare the first character of a string in assembly to see if its blank.

```
            mov byte [NAME], 40
            lea dx, [NAME]
            mov ah, 0ah
            int 21h

            cmp [NAME],""
            je somewhere
```

This doesnt work.. any advice?

Answer (score 2):

For starters, the int21/0ah puts the actual contents at `NAME+2` since at `NAME` you specify the buffer length and at `NAME+1` the actual length is returned. All of this is of course documented.

The `cmp` should use a size specification and also simple quotes. As such, `cmp byte [NAME+2], ' '` could work.

Comment: i used NAME times 43 db "$", so will it be cmp byte [NAME +2], '$' ?

Comment: @user3079563: What are you trying to achieve with `cmp byte [NAME +2], '$'`? If you wanto to check if the character is a space, compare against `' '`, not `'$'`. If you want to check if nothing was written to the buffer, check the byte at `[NAME+1]` (`number of characters actually read, excluding CR`)

Comment: if `[NAME]` holds the buffer len, and the system call doesn't clobber that, @user3079563 should just have the length byte in the data section, and leave out the `mov byte [NAME], 40` instruction, right?